# How do you use SetEnv to read variables in Apache?

Tags: apache, setenv

I want to set an env variable that has the DOC_ROOT info but nothing

```
SetEnv PROJECT_BASE %{ENV:DOC_ROOT}
SetEnv LAYOUT_HOME  %{ENV:PROJECT_BASE}"/html/app/wordpress/"
```

and then be able to access LAYOUT_HOME in php

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are accesible via :

$_SERVER["LAYOUT_HOME"] and $_SERVER["PROJECT_BASE"]  global variable.

A simple test if to execute the next command in php

`<?php  phpinfo(); ?>`

and check if the variable is present and is defined.

If not, then may be exist some restricting in the php installation ( for example in a share ambiance - sharedhosting)

Comment: well the problem is in htaccess file... i cant access the variables im using SetEnv with.. %{ENV:PROJECT_BASE} is not working

Answer (score -1):

So far it's not possible.
All you can do is to set request headers with RequestHeader.
So you'll have you variable in environ but with "HTTP_" prefix.

Comment: It's rather odd you answer it's "not possible" almost exactly 7 years after someone else already explained it was possible and how to do it. Maybe read accepted answers before adding your own saying what's *so far* not possible?