# Database Credentials Encryption - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, encryption

How can I encrypt my Database Credentials in CodeIgniter?

Database Creditable that exist in Config file.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? Just make this file inaccessible to the outsiders. That will do.

Comment: Encryption implies trying to hide/protect something from someone. Who are you trying to hide these config values from? Your application needs them to work, so your application needs to be able to decrypt them. If your application has the code to decrypt it, and the config file is part of the application, then anyone who has access to the config file should also have access to the means of decryption. Ergo, this seems pretty useless on the face of it, unless you can clarify more.

Comment: @deceze - I need to encrypt password in config file, If it is not possible then Is there is alternative for the same? I don't want that any one can access or harm my credentials.

Comment: Come on, I have written more about the topic here in the comments than you have. Clarify **what you want to protect from whom and why.** Only that's going to lead to the right solution.

Comment: Okay, So it is like No other User or anyone can access this file except owner. I need to protect this file. How can I do this?

Comment: Who is "the owner"? Who would be able to access this file in the first place and how? Anyone who has access to the server pretty much has access to this file as well. Or do you just want to keep this information out of your version control system? Be specific!

Comment: `chmod 600 <filename>` would have done what he wanted.

Comment: From https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-credentials : There are a couple of benefits of using encrypted credentials instead of environment keys:

Your credentials are encrypted. No one will be able to read your credentials without the key;
The encrypted credentials are saved in your repository. You'll have a history of the changes and who made them;
You can deploy credentials together with your code;
All secrets are in one location. Instead of managing multiple environment variables, everything is in one file.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using environment variables. Assuming you're using Apache. You can set these variables in your VirtualHost and reference these variables later.

This way you can hide your actual database values from the application but you're moving the storage of your passwords from your application into Apache.

[How do you use SetEnv to read variables in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010660/how-do-you-use-setenv-to-read-variables-in-apache)

I think this is what you're meaning to do. You can't completey hide these values from your app. At some layer they will need to be raw to your app.

You can also use `$_SERVER` or the `getenv()` function to retrieve the values you've set. [getenv() documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/httpd"
    ServerName mysite.local
    ServerAlias mysite.local
    SetEnv DB_HOST myhost
    SetEnv DB_USERNAME username
    SetEnv DB_PASSWORD password
    ...
    SetEnv DB_DBNAME dbase
</VirtualHost>

PHP
$db['default']['hostname'] = getenv('DB_HOST');
$db['default']['username'] = getenv('DB_USERNAME');
$db['default']['password'] = getenv('DB_PASSWORD');
$db['default']['database'] = getenv('DB_DBNAME');
...
```